# How i can use the Move procedure to fill a TList<T> Element?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need move the data stored in a array of bytes to a set of records located in a TList, but i'm getting this error

> E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

This code reproduce the issue.

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TData = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
  end;

//this code is only to show the issue, for simplicity i'm filling only the first  
//element of the TList but the real code needs fill N elements from a very big array.  
var
  List : TList<TData>;
  P : array [0..1023] of byte;
begin
  try
    List:=TList<TData>.Create;
    try
      List.Count:=1;
      //here i want to move the content of the P variable to the element 0
      Move(P[0],List[0], SizeOf(TData));

    finally
      List.Free;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

How i can copy the contents of a buffer to a TList Element

Comment: Define "need"? It seems you should say "want".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XE2, the internal storage for `TList<T>` is opaque and hidden. You cannot gain access to it by normal means. All access to elements of the list are copied – references to the underlying storage are not available. So you cannot blit to it using `Move`. If you want a structure that you can blit to, you should consider a dynamic array, `TArray<T>`.

You can always use the trick of implementing a class helper for `TList<TData>` that would expose the private variable `FItems`. That's pretty hacky but will do what you ask.

```
type
  __TListTData = TList<TData>;
  //defeat E2086 Type 'TList<T>' is not yet completely defined

type
  TListTDataHelper = class helper for TList<TData>
    procedure Blit(const Source; Count: Integer);
  end;

procedure TListTDataHelper.Blit(const Source; Count: Integer);
begin
  System.Move(Source, Pointer(FItems)^, Count*SizeOf(Self[0]));
end;
```

I guess you might want to put some parameter checking in `TListTDataHelper.Blit`, but I'll leave that to you.

If you were using XE3, you could access the private storage of `TList<T>` by using the [`List`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.List) property.

```
Move(P, Pointer(List.List)^, N*SizeOf(List[0]));
```

If you don't need to blit and can use a for loop then do it like this:

```
type
  PData = ^TData;
var
  i: Integer;
  Ptr: PData;
....
List.Count := N;
Ptr := PData(@P);
for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
begin
  List[i] := Ptr^;
  inc(Ptr);
end;
```

But I interpret your question that you wish to avoid this option.

Comment: Clever and completely bad idea 99.99% of the time. Please think of the person who comes after you and has to maintain the code containing this ugly kludge, and don't ever ever do this.

Comment: @Warren Yes, I think I'd use a for loop!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Move()`, try using the `TList<T>.Items[]` property setter instead and let the compiler and RTL handle the copying for you:

```
type
  PData = ^TData;
  ...

List[0] := PData(@P[0])^;
```

Comment: Question states a desire to blit N elements in one go

Comment: Nevertheless, the OP is asking for a loaded gun and wants to use it to do a job more suited to a fly-swatter, and pointing out that shooting oneself in the foot is a bad thing, advising them of that is preferable, in my view.